# Turning on rear defroster makes idle RPM stutter

Tags: bmw, idle, defroster

I have an e46 BMW and I recently noticed a problem which hasn't occurred before. While at a stop if I turn on the rear window defroster I notice that the engine idle RPM starts to stutter (goes down a bit) and then goes back to normal. Is the extra load sapping the spark plugs momentarily? Increased alternator load making the engine work harder? What could cause this and should I be concerned about it?

Comment: Check your battery connections and remove and clean them is necessary.

Comment: If the temperature is cold (ambient & engine) then the ecu may take a second or two to compensate the new load on the engine - happens on mine but fine once warmed up.

Comment: if the same happens when you turn on the headlights-heated seats-other high current aplications then it is normal it is just the engine adjusting to different  load at idle.

Comment: @trond No only seems to be rear defroster.